# How to automatically display first google search result in webView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I recently made a search bar that searches the users input on Google, now instead of displaying the Google search results i want it to just automatically display the first search result. Here is the code i currently have:

```
-(IBAction)searchInfo: (id)sender {
NSString *query = [googleBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%@" , query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];}
```

This code allows the user's text input in my search bar to be searched for on Google, but I now want it to automatically display the first result that comes up on Google.
My second part of this question is how would I add an algorithm that didn't just select the first result, but selected a specific search result and displayed it on the webView, also what type of algorithm would that be?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the google search result the item anchor element can be selected easily. Each of the individual search results are grouped inside **li** element of class name **'g'** and then inside it there is the link which you would want to click.

So, selecting the first clickable element is easy through javascript as;

```
  NSString *javascriptString = @"document.getElementsByClassName('g')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()";
```

Then to click the element you would simply execute the above string into the UIWebview as;

```
 [webView – stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javascriptString];
```

You would want to execute this code once the WebView finishes loading the request. So, implement the webview delegate and once the search result request loads, execute the above code.

Comment: Thank you very much i appreciate your answer a lot but when i use the 'search' button on the keyboard it still displays the searches from Google, how would i make it do the same thing as my 'searchInfo' button and go straight to the first result automatically. Thanks

Comment: Also, its very strange but sometimes the 'searchInfo' button displays search results from Google and doesn't go to the first result, but then equally sometimes it implements the code and goes to the first result, did I do something wrong? :(